# Can we navigate to a new view when clicking a sub menu inside a Expandable table view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a HRMS screen containing many buttons. I want to categorise each button based on a more its functionality like

Attendance->
    Attendance Marking 
    Attendance register

Leave->
    Leave Request
    Leave OD Authorise
    Leave OD Approve

Others->
    HolidayList
    Leave Balance

Right now my screen look like this[image: HRMS]

I am trying to implement the expandable list view. The logic is simple that when clicking a sub menu I want to go to the specific View controller associated with it. Although I know how to do this using simple table view using

> func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath
>   indexPath: NSIndexPath!)

I cant figure out how to implement it while using the expandable table view. I googled about the same but couldn't get a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    { 
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            /*The first row of the first section was tapped.
              Put code here that you would like to execute when the
              first row of the first section is tapped*/
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            /*The second row of the first section was tapped.
              Put code here that you would like to execute when the
              second row of the first section is tapped*/
        }
    }  

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    { 
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            /*The first row of the second section was tapped.
              Put code here that you would like to execute when the
              first row of the second section is tapped*/
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            /*The second row of the second section was tapped.
              Put code here that you would like to execute when the
              second row of the second section is tapped*/
        }
    }  
}
```

with expandable tableView same as with normal tableviews. Just put your code to call new viewController in the above method for the required tableView row.

One thing to keep in mind is that when you are using multiple sections (which your would be if you are using expandable tableView) then the indexing for the rows for each section starts from zero.

For example there are three sections in your tableView with three rows each, their indexing would be like this

- Section 0

  - Row 0
  - Row 1
  - Row 2
- Section 1

  - Row 0
  - Row 1
  - Row 2
- Section 2

  - Row 0
  - Row 1
  - Row 2

So you need to check for both the section and the row in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Can u please elaborate how do we check for both row and section when a didSelectRow AtIndexPath method is called